# compress blank spaces in uiview

Tags: iphone, uiview

Is there any way by which we could ask the UIView to compress the blank spaces in the screen, for example, I have the following elements

```
label1
label2
label3
```

I have built the view via IB.

At runtime, I hide 1 field, eg: `label2.hidden = YES;`
Now the view appears like this:

```
label1
space 
label3
```

Instead I would like:

```
label1
label3 - without the blank white space in the middle.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a built in feature. You have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For remove the space of Lable2, you can realloc frame for lable3 at runTime same the frame of lable2 than lable3 will be set on place of lable2.